# Thriller/horror movie where the mother is behind the bathroom door but has no eyes or nose

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a thriller movie I saw ~10 years ago on TV and there was a scene where one of the characters has a nightmare of opening the bathroom door from the inside, and sees his mother behind the door, except she has no eyes and two holes instead of a nose and possibly very long fingers. Another scene I remember is one where one of the characters is wrapped in some transparent material and is screaming while another character is dragging his body across the floor of a house.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the supernatural or science fictional aspects of the film? As it is, it sounds like a nightmare and someone with a plastic bag. :)

Comment: Also, I recommend looking through the prompts at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to help elicit further details to edit into your question, and to read the [tour] so that you'll know when and how to accept an answer.